# Is there some way to automatically export the query results in PL/SQL Developer? CSV or XLSX for example

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I've tried some codes like these below:

```
select /*csv*/ * from users;
```

,

```
spool "C:/Users/Douglas/Desktop";
select /*csv*/ *
  from users;
spool off;
```

AND

```
--CSV=C:\Users\dvferreira\Desktop\temp.csv
select * from users;
```

Is there anything else I can try?

PL/SQL Developer 15.0.0.2050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PL/SQL Developer comment directives only take effect if you actually export the data. You still need to right-click on the header of the result grid, click Export Results, and then click either "CSV file" or "Excel file". Comment directives don't fully automate exports, but they at least save you a few clicks. See the PDF manual in Help --> User's Guide for more information about that feature.

Comment: It's not fully automated, but it's very much worth it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL*Developer shares the same codebase as SQLCl, the SQLCl command SET SQLFORMAT works:

```
set sqlformat CSV

spool "c:\temp\out.csv"

select * from user_tables;

spool off
```

Then 'Run As Script'.

Comment: This question relates to Allround Automations' PL/SQL Developer, not Oracle SQL Developer.